# Creating custom spectra graphs

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, software, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I wanted to make a few custom spectra graphs for some homework questions I'm assigning. The issue is that the Education Board issued datasheets do not reflect online images. They often say that bonds absorb different wavelengths to images I can find like this one:

[image]

I was hoping that I could make my own graphs similar to this. I want to manually generate spectra that would match the Government Sheets' data on what bonds absorb what.

What is some software that could do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a chemistry question per se; but if you have the underlying data, this sort of graph is fairly easy to generate in any (reasonably high-level) programming language you may want to do. Python (with matplotlib), R, or Matlab are probably the most common choices in science. The tougher part of this is getting the numbers to plot. If you have those numbers, then it's simple: plotting an array of intensities (or logs or whatever) against an array of wavelengths, changing the axis labels, and adding a title will be covered in basic plotting tutorials.

Comment: @orthocresol The problem is that I don't have the numbers. Ideally some kind of drag and drop of points would be nice. Currently I'm just roughly hand drawing the curves but it'd be nice to make it look more professional

Comment: "drag and drop of points" -- then you are probably looking for graphic design software like Inkscape which will let you draw Bezier curves. I don't know if that's simpler, or whether it's in fact easier to use a pencil & ruler to extract the data from the graph you're trying to reproduce so that you can re-plot it in your language of choice.

Comment: @JohnHon If «I don't have these numbers» equates to «but I have the relevant graphs as illustrations (from different sources)», then you need a digitizer (e.g. [webplotdigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/)). The subsequent creation of the data can be automated / scripted with a template for [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/) into bitmap or vector format.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate such custom spectra graphs using an open source python library : [orca-uv](https://github.com/radi0sus/orca_uv) and the [ORCA](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/first_steps/install.html) tool

The orca-uv tool takes an .out file generated by ORCA for UVVis spectroscopy calculation and saves a .PNG file of the spectral graph.

Using a sample .out file obtained from the [ORCA UVVis tutorial electronic spectrum](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/spec/UVVis.html#the-electronic-spectrum),
a minimum reproducible example is shown below on a Google Colab Notebook:

```
!git clone https://github.com/radi0sus/orca_uv

sample_orca_output = '''
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ABSORPTION SPECTRUM VIA TRANSITION ELECTRIC DIPOLE MOMENTS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
State   Energy    Wavelength  fosc         T2        TX        TY        TZ
        (cm-1)      (nm)                 (au**2)    (au)      (au)      (au)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   19699.5    507.6   0.047917124   0.80078   0.87904  -0.16736   0.00724
   2   30354.1    329.4   0.012327447   0.13370   0.05769   0.36102  -0.00597
   3   31373.4    318.7   0.023725133   0.24896  -0.48626   0.08573  -0.07183
   4   32906.2    303.9   0.002354014   0.02355  -0.04012  -0.14813   0.00027
   5   34099.1    293.3   0.176508288   1.70411   1.27793  -0.24569  -0.10310
'''



with open("sample_orca.out", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(sample_orca_output)

!python3 /content/orca_uv/orca-uv.py /content/sample_orca.out
```

This saves an image called: `sample_orca-abs.png` in the root directory.

And the spectral plot in the image `sample_orca-abs.png` looks like this:

[image]

And to get the .out file for your data you can follow the [ORCA UVVis tutorial](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/spec/UVVis.html)